# How to update one json object in php?

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am doing some stuffz for work and i need to store random data in one json file. There are multiple forms on multiple pages i.e:
page1: form name="form1"
page2: form name="form2"

each of forms is saved into save.php file which is supposed to write into json file.

The problem is, whenever I submit form1, it clears entire json file and submits form1. same goes for form2 etc. How to just update object without clearing other objects if they are not submitted?

I have tried using isset($_POST['input1']) array("form1":post['input1']) and accordingly for form2, but it still updates entire file instead just one object.

```
$json = json_encode($array);
file_put_contents('things.json', $json);
```

//don't yell at me that syntax above is invalid, i know that. it is just sketch to show you what i am trying to do.

Comment: $data = json_decode(file_put_contents('things.json')); will give you an array of existing data. Now append your new data and write again using 

$data['input2'] = 'xyz';
file_put_contents('things.json', json_encode($data));

Comment: @Ima has answered your question/problem. In reality, your web page may serve multiple users at the same time. If this the case, you could run into a problem where multiple requests/users could write the same file and your data could become corrupted. You may consider generating a random identifier within the form so you can have a dedicated file for that or storing this data completely in a database.

Comment: If multiple users are using your page simultaneously, you can endup with loosing data